# Should flat owner (in multi-story apartment, living beneath another flat) take both Building insurance & contents insurance

Tags: united-kingdom, insurance

This is UK specific question.
In case of flat, everyone is aware that there's some building wide structure insurance which management company arranged on behalf of flat owners & the freeholder.

But my query is specific to a scenario - Should flat owner (in multi-story apartment , living beneath another flat viz- flat owner on say floor 3 of 5 story building) take both Building insurance & contents insurance, in order to insure against issues like leakage from upstair flat to their flat or any potential leakage flat to flat beneath them?
Also issues like soundproofing between floors.

Because my understanding is that common building insurance only covers leakage from roof to the top floor flats & not the leakage from flats to downstair flats.
Or does home content insurance is sufficient to cover both?

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need contents insurance. You shouldn’t need buildings insurance, and you probably won’t be able to find anyone to sell it to you. You’re already paying for buildings insurance in your service charge. You might consider legal costs insurance in case you need to sue some complicated combination of the freeholder, the management company, the buildings insurance company and the leaseholder of the flat above. But if you’re actually buying a leasehold flat, speak to your solicitor and get him to make sure that you’re covered.

Comment: Flat is already purchased & its now out of builder's warranty period. I contacted estate management company & they told - they only cover top floor flats for leakage as they have the roof and for middle floor flat owners should directly deal with upstairs flat owner. Is this normal?

Comment: Also I checked insurance comparison sites and content insurance comes circa £7/month and content&building insurance is £18/month. So is it wise to take it anyways on safer side..

Comment: @user2451016 Yes, that’s normal. That’s why I suggested legal costs insurance.